# how to remove u' from my input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

how to remove `u` from my string?

i am getting this in my server

```
{
    id: 4,
    resource_uri: "/api/v1/status/4",
    status: "[u'eriks']"
}
```

my input field

```
<p><label>Status</label>
<input type="text" class="status"  ui-select2="select2Options" placeholder="Choose your inventory's status" ng-model="newinfo.status.status"></p>
```

`$scope.list_of_string = 'viss kartiba';
    $scope.select2Options = {
        'multiple': true,
        'simple_tags': true,
        'tags': 'remonta', 'saplisis', 'slikts stavoklis'  // Can be empty list.
    };`

I am using ui.bootstrap tags http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: i think it would be better if you fix your server side code, because it is returning a unicode string instead of an array.

Comment: @idursun It looks like it's returning a string representation of an array of length one, containing a unicode string...

Comment: Yes, that is what I said and I suggest him to fix it. Server should return data that matters, not string representation of internal data.

Comment: @idursun yes, but i dont know how the ui.bootstrap select2 works. It automaticly ads 'u when i make normal input field it get normal string with no problems

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the bit in between the single quotes, you could do something like

```
"[u'eriks']".match(/\'(.*)\'/)[1]
```

This matches anything within the single quotes (returns `"eriks"`).